# SQL Where clause that is different for each line

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that looks like this
[image]

I need to count the number of entries with a particular answer id.
However, I need the count to only count the user's latest answer ie. I need the where 
clause to dynamically check for each entry, that it is the user's latest answer.

This is the start I currently have.
How would I actually make it work?

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT social.useranswers.uid)
FROM useranswers
WHERE useranswers.answerid = $1;
    AND userAnswers.date = (
        SELECT MAX(userAnswers.date) 
        FROM userAnswers 
        WHERE uid=uid
        )
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: picture is better than text

Comment: No, picture is worse than text.

Comment: If you are counting, does it matter whether it's the latest answer? Are you not saying "no matter how often a user answers, I just want to count one of their answers in my result"?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `limit` clause inside `subquery` :

```
select count(*)
from useranswers u
where id = (select u1.id
            from useranswers u1
            where u1.uid = u.uid
            order by date desc
            limit 1
           );
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that I understand you right, explanation isn't clear enough, but you can use this code to get number of each last `uid` entry with a particular `id`

```
CREATE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (
      id       CHAR(1),
      uid      VARCHAR,
      dt       DATE,
      storyid  CHAR(1),
      answerid CHAR(1)
    );

    --Just some sample data for testing purpose
    INSERT INTO tmp VALUES ('1', '1', '2018-05-20', '1', '1');
    INSERT INTO tmp VALUES ('2', '1', '2018-05-21', '1', '1');
    INSERT INTO tmp VALUES ('1', '1', '2018-05-22', '1', '1');
    INSERT INTO tmp VALUES ('4', '2', '2018-05-21', '1', '1');
    INSERT INTO tmp VALUES ('5', '2', '2018-05-22', '1', '1');
    INSERT INTO tmp VALUES ('6', '3', '2018-05-20', '1', '1');
    INSERT INTO tmp VALUES ('7', '4', '2018-05-21', '1', '1');
    INSERT INTO tmp VALUES ('8', '4', '2018-05-21', '2', '1');
    INSERT INTO tmp VALUES ('1', '4', '2018-05-22', '2', '1');

    SELECT
      count(*)
      , uid
    FROM (
           SELECT
             id
             , uid
             , dt
             , row_number()
               OVER (
                 PARTITION BY uid
                 ORDER BY dt DESC ) num
           FROM tmp
         ) tt
    WHERE num = 1 AND id = '1'
    GROUP BY uid;
```